# Does AWS Pinpoint support Notification Center and In App messages?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-pinpoint

Does AWS Pinpoint support Notification Center and In App messages ? I couldn't find the information on AWS pinpoint docs.

Comment: I've been using pinpoint for a while now, it does support push notifications but I'm not sure about In App messages I don't think it supports that

Answer (score 1):

> The Messages resource represents a direct message, which is a one-time message that you send directly to a limited audience without creating a campaign. You can send a direct message to as many as 100 recipients. The message can be a **push notification** for users of your mobile app, **an SMS message**, **an email**, **or a voice message**.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/apireference/apps-application-id-messages.html